# Como corrigir este código PHP no Raspbian (Raspberry Pi 2)?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

Estou criando 2 projetos de monitoramento aqui na empresa com 2 páginas de monitoramento que usará PHP e HTML e vão rodar em placa Raspberry Pi 2 (Raspbian). O código está bem simples, consigo abri-lo normalmente no Windows, porém no Raspbian está ocorrendo conforme imagem abaixo (desculpem a qualidade, tirei do celular):

[image: Erro PHP Raspbian]

Ele apresenta uma parte do código PHP e o final, depois adiciona a imagem (no html) só que sem o restante do código. Segue abaixo o começo do código para ter uma ideia:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<!--        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 30000);
        </script>

        <title>Topologia Band</title>
    </head>

    <?php
    function teste_ping ($host, $ip="173.0.0.1")
    {
        $data = date('_d_m');

        $f = fopen("ping$data.csv", 'r');
        if ($f) 
        { 
            while (($linha=fgetcsv($f))!==FALSE) 
            {
                if ((string)$ip==(string)$linha[0]) 
                {
                    if($linha[1] == "1")
                    {
                        echo "<div class='$host'><i class='verde fa fa-2x fa-wifi'></i></div>";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        echo "<div class='$host'><i class='vermelho fa fa-2x fa-wifi'></i></div>";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                elseif ((string)$ip!=(string)$linha[0])
                {
                    echo "<div class='$host'><i class='azul fa fa-2x fa-wifi'></i></div>";
                }
            }
        fclose($f);
        }
    }
?>
    <body>
        <header><h1>Mapa da rede EM TESTE</h1></header>
            <div class="topologia_rede">
                <img class="img_topologia_rede" src="img/img_topologia.png">
            </div>

            <?php teste_ping('div_torre_band', 'www.google.com.br'); ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_fibra_1gb', 'www.googasle.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_telefonia_publica', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_e1_embratel', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_GRU', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_embratel_20mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_linktel_20mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_linktel_10mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_tvminuto_vl-mariana', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_link_2mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_radio_30mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_embratel_100mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_virtua_30mb', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_rede_publica', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_uol_diveo', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_oi_wifi', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
            <?php teste_ping('div_VCP', 'www.google.com.br');   ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Poderiam me auxiliar em como resolver?

Obs1: Já tentei nos navegadores: Midori, Epiphany e Chromium e persiste o problema;

Obs2: Já atualizei o apache, PHP5 e o serviço está OK;

Obs3: Status do apache: [image: Status Apache]

Comment: O script PHP não está sendo interpretado, por isso exibe como texto. Certifique-se de que o PHP esteja configurado no Apache.

Comment: Aparentemente está configurado. Teria alguma dica de comandos que posso utilizar para usar como tentativa?

Comment: Crie um arquivo info.php e coloque esse código `<?php phpinfo();` salve e execute pelo browser `http://localhost/pingphp/site/info.php`.  
Deve aparecer uma página de cor púrpura com informações do php

Comment: Fiz o comando e apareceu a linha de comando no Browser. Vou editar a pergunta inserindo a imagem do apache2 status pra você ver como está "aparentemente OK" mas não sei mais como fazer. Já edito a pergunta com a imagem.

Comment: Agora está claro que o PHP não está sendo carregado pelo Apache. Apenas adicione o PHP como módulo do Apache. Aí mesmo no console do raspi, digite `service apache2 -M` que retornará a lista de módulos carregados pelo Apache. Provavelmente não mostrará o módulo do PHP na lista. Então vc deve adicionar o módulo no `httpd.conf` e reiniciar o Apache.